# How to Open Facebook Page with a Like Button via Android Intent

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I'm using:

```
fb://facewebmodal/f?href=https://facebook.com/pageName
```

in an Android intent (if the user has the facebook app installed) to open pageName in the facebook app instead of the browser.

The problem I'm running into is the page that is opened in the fb app is the correct page, i.e. pageName, but it doesn't have a like button anywhere on the page.  Anyone have any ideas how to maybe pull the page up from an Android intent so that the like button is displayed as well?

I have tried passing different urls such as "https://facebook.com/pageId", "https://m.facebook.com/pageName", and variations thereof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fb://facewebmodal/f?href=someUrl` will always open to a page without a like button.

If you want it to open to a page with a like button you have to use `fb://page/pageId` where pageId is the id of the Facebook page you're trying to open.

Comment: Be sure to use numeric page id (it's not the same as page name). It should look something like this fb://page/310299785735132. You can check pageId here https://findmyfbid.com/